# Capturing output of subprocess.run() in Windows

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

Under Windows and Python3, I'm converting some old code that uses `os.system()` to use `subprocess.run()`, but am having trouble capturing the output to stdout and stderr.

Here's what I get from a simple `dir c:\`:

```
r = subprocess.run(['dir', 'c:\\'], check=True, universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

r.stdout
Out[56]: '$GetCurrent\t\t  Program\\ Files\t       Users\t   cygwin64\n$Recycle.Bin\t\t  Program\\ Files\\ (x86)        WPy64-3740  findEm\nBOOTNXT\t\t\t  ProgramData\t\t       Windows\t   microchip\nBrother\t\t\t  Program_Files\t\t       antiword    pagefile.sys\nDocuments\\ and\\ Settings  Recovery\t\t       bin\t   swapfile.sys\nPerfLogs\t\t  System\\ Volume\\ Information  bootmgr\n'

type(r.stdout)
Out[57]: str
```

What's with all the '\t' (tabs, I suppose) and '\n' (newlines) in the output?

How do I convert the strings '\t' and '\n' in the result into actual tabs and newlines for printing?

Comment: You're looking at the repr (representation) of a string object. Use `print(r.stdout)` to display the string.

Comment: BTW, you must have a "dir.exe" program in `PATH`, because otherwise `dir` is a CMD shell command in Windows, which requires passing `shell=True` and passing an args string instead of a list. That said, if you do use CMD's internal `dir` command, I recommend using `shell=False` and running `cmd /u /c dir <...>` to get UTF-16 output (i.e. Python's "utf-16le" encoding). The file system is Unicode and requires a Unicode encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16).  Without the `/u` option, the result is a best-fit encoding to the current console input codepage, which is generally useless.

Comment: @ErykSun Make it an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

I got example like this , but using sqlcmd :

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

connection_string = 'sqlcmd -S %s -U %s -P %s -d %s -i %s -r0' %(self.host,self.user,self.password,self.db,file)
session = Popen(connection_string, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = session.communicate()
#Where stderr is the error
print(stderr)
#Where is the output 
print(stdout)
```